# Ubuntu 15.04 on Lenovo Yoga 3 14

Tags: nvidia, 15.04, lenovo

I'm considering buying the Lenovo Yoga 3 14" because it is convertible and has a GPU Nvidia GT940M.
Has anyone have encountered any issue with Ubuntu ? I haven't seen any question here about it but the laptop is still pretty new.
I'm worried about:

- the touch screen
- switching of the display
- switching between chipset and nvidia graphic cards
- wifi

Those are issues I have seen reported here about other lenovo laptop. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe you've seen it already, but here is some info regarding ubuntu on thinkpad yoga, which could be related to yoga: http://askubuntu.com/a/596552/95365

Comment: @streetturtle Yeah thanks I've seen it already. It's not the same model and there was no update about Ubuntu 15 that's why I'm asking "again"